# Lucene white space analyzer ignoring phrases?

Tags: lucene

I'm updating a document in Lucene, but when I search for the full value in one of the fields no results come back. If I search for just one word, then I get a result back.

This example comes from chapter 2 of the Lucene in Action 2nd Edition book and I'm using the Lucene 3 Java Library.

Here's the main logic

```
"Document fields show new value when updated, and not old value" in {
        getHitCount("city", "Amsterdam") must equal(1)

        val update = new Document
        update add new Field("id", "1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED)
        update add new Field("country", "Netherlands", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO)
        update add new Field("contents", "Den Haag has a lot of museums", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED)
        update add new Field("city", "Den Haag", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED)

        wr updateDocument(new Term("id", "1"), update)
        wr close

        getHitCount("city", "Amsterdam") must equal(0)
        getHitCount("city", "Den Haag") must equal(1)
    }
```

It's the last line in the above that fails - the hit count is 0. If I change the query to either "Den" or "Haag" then I get 1 hit.

Here is all the setup and dependencies. Note how the writer uses a white space query analyzer as the book suggests. Is this the problem?

```
  override def beforeEach{
        dir = new RAMDirectory

        val wri = writer
        for (i <- 0 to ids.length - 1) {
            val doc = new Document
            doc add new Field("id", ids(i), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED)
            doc add new Field("country", unindexed(i), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO)
            doc add new Field("contents", unstored(i), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED)
            doc add new Field("city", text(i), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED)
            wri addDocument doc
        }
        wri close

        wr = writer
    }

 var dir: RAMDirectory = _
    def writer = new IndexWriter(dir, new WhitespaceAnalyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)
    var wr: IndexWriter = _

def getHitCount(field: String, q: String): Int = {
        val searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir)
        val query = new TermQuery(new Term(field, q))
        val hitCount = searcher.search(query, 1).totalHits
        searcher.close()
        hitCount
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at PhraseQuery instead of TermQuery.